# Perl script to print lines between empty lines

Tags: regex, perl

i read a similar question at ([How can I print all the lines between the previous and next empty lines when a match is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546985/how-can-i-print-all-the-lines-between-the-previous-and-next-empty-lines-when-a-m))! and tried to print all lines between empty lines, but it is not printing so. Here is the script i tried, kindly correct it to work for my requirement.

```
my @file = <IN>;
for (0 .. $#file) {
if ($file[$_] =~ /Match/){
    my $start = $_;
    while ($start >= 0 && $file[$start] !~ /^$/) {
        $start--; # $start points to first empty line
    }
    my $end = $_;
    while ($end <= $#file && $file[$end] !~ /^$/) {
        $end++; # $end points to next empty line
    }
 print OUT "\n@file[$start+1..$end-1]"; #it should print between two empty lines right??
}
}
```

Input File:

```
wire enable,GSMC_G8,mkf_g,un1_G11_0, GND_net_1, VCC, G8, G16, Q_RNIUQAA,        CK_c, reset_c, 
    G0_c, G1_c, G17_c, G2_c, G3_c, G17_c_i, GND_1, VCC_0;

INBUF G3_pad (.PAD(G3), .Y(G3_c));
dff_0_1 DFF_1 (.G17_c(G17_c), .reset_c(reset_c), .CK_c(CK_c), 
    .G0_c(G0_c), .G8(G8));
GND GND_i_0 (.Y(GND_1));
NOR2 G3_pad_RNIUUQF (.A(G8), .B(G3_c), .Y(G16));
INV G17_pad_RNO (.A(G17_c), .Y(G17_c_i));
VCC VCC_i (.Y(VCC));
CLKBUF CK_pad (.PAD(CK), .Y(CK_c));

endmodule
```

Output file required:

```
INBUF G3_pad (.PAD(G3), .Y(G3_c));
dff_0_1 DFF_1 (.G17_c(G17_c), .reset_c(reset_c), .CK_c(CK_c), 
    .G0_c(G0_c), .G8(G8));
GND GND_i_0 (.Y(GND_1));
NOR2 G3_pad_RNIUUQF (.A(G8), .B(G3_c), .Y(G16));
INV G17_pad_RNO (.A(G17_c), .Y(G17_c_i));
VCC VCC_i (.Y(VCC));
CLKBUF CK_pad (.PAD(CK), .Y(CK_c));
```

Comment: Please include an example input file, and the desired output. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, please `use strict` and `use warnings`. There are several syntax problems in your code. Math operators are not interpolated in strings. Your `print` statement doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flip-flop operator](http://perlhacks.com/2014/01/dots-perl/).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Turn flip-flop on at the first empty line
  # And then off at the next empty line
  if (/^$/ ... /^$/) {
    # Ignore the two empty lines
    next unless /\S/;
    print;
  }
}

__DATA__
wire enable,GSMC_G8,mkf_g,un1_G11_0, GND_net_1, VCC, G8, G16, Q_RNIUQAA,        CK_c, reset_c, 
    G0_c, G1_c, G17_c, G2_c, G3_c, G17_c_i, GND_1, VCC_0;

INBUF G3_pad (.PAD(G3), .Y(G3_c));
dff_0_1 DFF_1 (.G17_c(G17_c), .reset_c(reset_c), .CK_c(CK_c), 
    .G0_c(G0_c), .G8(G8));
GND GND_i_0 (.Y(GND_1));
NOR2 G3_pad_RNIUUQF (.A(G8), .B(G3_c), .Y(G16));
INV G17_pad_RNO (.A(G17_c), .Y(G17_c_i));
VCC VCC_i (.Y(VCC));
CLKBUF CK_pad (.PAD(CK), .Y(CK_c));

endmodule
```

I've used the `DATA` filehandle here to make it easy to demonstrate what's happening. It's easy to swap that out for another filehandle.

Comment: When you say "I tried the same thing", what **exactly** did you do?

Comment: My code works. If your code doesn't work, then you must have changed my code in some way. Without knowing what those changes are, there's no way I can help you any more.

Comment: Did you notice that you need the three-dot version of the flip-flop operator?